# Is the Google Analytics Realtime API v3 still in beta?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm slightly confused whether the real time v3 api is in beta.
I applied for access using this form https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc9OpoDGB3tBD7oy1OG9fyum8KBIxs-2ihPCsHp13WTnM-SSQ/viewform well over 24 hours ago but my requests to the api are still getting an error of "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile."

I can see documents relating to this beta dating back to 2013 - it would seem very strange for something to be in beta for this long.

Has this project been 'sunsetted' - i.e. am I wasting my time trying to get access to it?

Comment: Im not sure why exactly it is still in beta, I think it had to do with wanting to monitor how much it was being used.   It can take a while to get whitelisted but you wont hear from them you just have to try it from time to time.  You should get access within a month i would expect  if you dont i can try to find someone to ping

Comment: Great, thanks for your help! I'll let you know how I get on

Comment: The team says that RT api is publicly available you shouldn't need to be whitelisted.  (No the documentation hasnt been updated dont ask) Could you add your code and show me the error message you are getting?

Comment: This API is in beta since 7-8 years. No need to apply anywhere, you can simply start using it.

Comment: Problem is with the credentials you're providing..